# For AWS, why can't I create an account when I run my Android application through the emulator?

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

While setting up Amazon Web Services, I set up Cognito as well as my user pool, and so I get the sign-in screen when I run the emulator in Android Studio. However, it doesn't let me press Create New Account or Forgot Your Password. Also, when I enter fake usernames/passwords, I would expect it to say "sign-in failed" or something, but the app doesn't respond at all.

[Emulator Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1VTi.png)

Why does this happen? I attached the code that I get when I run the emulator.

```html
07-22 19:13:00.762    3684-3684/com.amazon.mysampleapp I/art﹕ Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
07-22 19:13:00.800    3684-3684/com.amazon.mysampleapp W/System﹕ ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.amazon.mysampleapp-1/lib/x86
07-22 19:13:00.808    3684-3684/com.amazon.mysampleapp I/MultiDex﹕ VM with version 2.1.0 has multidex support
07-22 19:13:00.808    3684-3684/com.amazon.mysampleapp I/MultiDex﹕ install
07-22 19:13:00.808    3684-3684/com.amazon.mysampleapp I/MultiDex﹕ VM has multidex support, MultiDex support library is disabled.
07-22 19:13:00.809    3684-3684/com.amazon.mysampleapp D/Application﹕ Application.onCreate - Initializing application...
07-22 19:13:00.809    3684-3684/com.amazon.mysampleapp D/AWSMobileClient﹕ Initializing AWS Mobile Client...
07-22 19:13:00.810    3684-3684/com.amazon.mysampleapp D/IdentityManager﹕ IdentityManager init
07-22 19:13:00.831    3684-3684/com.amazon.mysampleapp D/CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider﹕ Loading credentials from SharedPreferences
07-22 19:13:00.831    3684-3684/com.amazon.mysampleapp D/CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider﹕ No valid credentials found in SharedPreferences
07-22 19:13:00.861    3684-3684/com.amazon.mysampleapp D/AWSMobileClient﹕ AWS Mobile Client is OK
07-22 19:13:00.861    3684-3684/com.amazon.mysampleapp D/Application﹕ Application.onCreate - Application initialized OK
07-22 19:13:00.866    3684-3684/com.amazon.mysampleapp D/SplashActivity﹕ onCreate
07-22 19:13:01.000    3684-3694/com.amazon.mysampleapp I/art﹕ Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 9931(594KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 43% free, 2MB/3MB, paused 488us total 107.712ms
07-22 19:13:00.999    3684-3701/com.amazon.mysampleapp D/AWSMobileClient﹕ AWS Mobile Client is OK
07-22 19:13:01.004    3684-3701/com.amazon.mysampleapp D/SplashActivity﹕ Launching Sign-in Activity...
07-22 19:13:01.039    3684-3703/com.amazon.mysampleapp D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
07-22 19:13:01.065    3684-3684/com.amazon.mysampleapp D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xaaabf5b0, tid 3684
07-22 19:13:01.374    3684-3703/com.amazon.mysampleapp D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xaaabf6a0, tid 3703
07-22 19:13:01.406    3684-3698/com.amazon.mysampleapp D/CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider﹕ Identity id is changed
07-22 19:13:01.406    3684-3698/com.amazon.mysampleapp D/CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider﹕ Saving identity id to SharedPreferences
07-22 19:13:01.406    3684-3698/com.amazon.mysampleapp D/CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider﹕ Clearing credentials from SharedPreferences
07-22 19:13:01.406    3684-3698/com.amazon.mysampleapp D/CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider﹕ Saving identity id to SharedPreferences
07-22 19:13:01.477    3684-3703/com.amazon.mysampleapp I/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Initialized EGL, version 1.4
07-22 19:13:01.585    3684-3703/com.amazon.mysampleapp W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
07-22 19:13:01.585    3684-3703/com.amazon.mysampleapp W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xaa9a2e00, error=EGL_SUCCESS
07-22 19:13:03.101    3684-3703/com.amazon.mysampleapp W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
07-22 19:13:03.101    3684-3703/com.amazon.mysampleapp W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xaaacc7e0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
07-22 19:13:04.252    3684-3684/com.amazon.mysampleapp I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 52 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-22 19:13:04.808    3684-3703/com.amazon.mysampleapp E/Surface﹕ getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xaa9a87e0
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks like the output from an app generated using AWS Mobile Hub.  Mobile Hub does not support Cognito User Pools at this time and the code that it does generate for sign up/sign in is all stubbed.  If you want a working sample of Cognito User Pools with sign up/sign in functionality, [this blog post](https://mobile.awsblog.com/post/TxNYVQQ3A2LT6Y/Using-Android-SDK-with-Amazon-Cognito-Your-User-Pools) discusses the service and contains a link to the Android sample.